# scala generic type parameter produces ClassCastException about converting java.lang.Double into double

Tags: scala, gatling

Here's a stripped down, minimal version of the class causing the problem:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

final case class Template[InnerType]()(implicit innerTypeTag: TypeTag[InnerType], innerClassTag: ClassTag[InnerType]) {
    def get(name: String, session: Session) =
        session(name).as[InnerType]
}
```

and usage that produces the exception:

```
.exec(session => session.set("d", 2.0)) // this stores value 2.0 in a Gatling session variable called 'd'
.exec{ session =>
    val foo = new Template[Double]()
    println(session("d").as[Double]) // this retrieves 'd' correctly, printing 2.0
    println(session("d").as[java.lang.Double]) // this retrieves 'd' correctly, printing 2.0
    println(foo.get("d", session)) // this triggers an error: j.l.ClassCastException: Can't cast attribute 'd' '2.0' of type class java.lang.Double into double'
    session
}
```

Why is there a difference between `session("d").as[Double]` and `session("d").as[InnerType]` if `InnerType` is `Double`? How can I fix this?

Best I can tell, it's taking the primitive type and converting it to the boxed version, but I haven't been able to find a way to reverse this, i.e. `.as[InnerType.primitive]`

The work-around I've come up with is a bit of a pain, as it requires this for all primitives:

```
if (typeTag[InnerType].tpe <:< typeTag[Double].tpe)
    session(variableName).as[Double].asInstanceOf[InnerType]
else if (typeTag[InnerType].tpe <:< typeTag[Int].tpe)
    session(variableName).as[Int].asInstanceOf[InnerType]
...
else
    session(variableName).as[InnerType]
```

Comment: `.as` works because it takes a `TypeCaster`, the one for `Double` [knows both types](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/934885be192afba56af3ec3e388e269a04b2ed1c/gatling-commons/src/main/scala/io/gatling/commons/util/TypeHelper.scala#L209). You're using a `TypeTag`, which gives you a [less capable caster](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/934885be192afba56af3ec3e388e269a04b2ed1c/gatling-commons/src/main/scala/io/gatling/commons/util/TypeHelper.scala#L48).

Comment: If you need more elaboration, I can write an answer.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung if elaboration would result in a less messy workaround, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your function, you take two implicit arguments. `innerTypeTag: TypeTag[InnerType], innerClassTag: ClassTag[InnerType]`.

In the function body, you call `.as[InnerType]`, which requires the implicit argument `TypeCaster[InnerType]`.

The `TypeCaster` implicitly supplied to `.as` by your function is "derived" from the function [genericTypeCaster](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/934885be192afba56af3ec3e388e269a04b2ed1c/gatling-commons/src/main/scala/io/gatling/commons/util/TypeHelper.scala#L48).

Explicitly supplying the arguments, the body of your `get` method looks like this:

```scala
session(name).as[InnerType](
  TypeCaster.genericTypeCaster(innerClassTag),
  ... // other implicit parameters
)
```

The `genericTypeCaster` does not know about `Double` and `java.lang.Double` and just act according to the class tag, so that's why your code fails.

---

If you call `.as[Double]` directly, the implicit argument needed is `TypeCaster[Double]`. Because there is [a `DoubleCaster` of this exact type](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/934885be192afba56af3ec3e388e269a04b2ed1c/gatling-commons/src/main/scala/io/gatling/commons/util/TypeHelper.scala#L209), it is picked over the generic (and dumber) one.

In other words, `session("d").as[Double]` looks like this, explicitly.

```scala
session("d").as[Double](
  TypeCaster.DoubleCaster,
  ... // other implicit parameters
)
```

This caster knows both `Double` and `java.lang.Double`, and also parses double values from strings.

---

If you understand the difference between the two caster, fixing is easy:

```scala
final case class Template[InnerType]()(implicit innerClassTag: ClassTag[InnerType], innerTypeCaster: TypeCaster[InnerType]) {
    def get(name: String, session: Session) =
        session(name).as[InnerType]
}
```

So when you create `val foo = new Template[Double]()`, `foo` will use the more powerful `DoubleCaster`.